# how to solve database Problem?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

```
Decimal  zipCode = [SELECT zipcode__c FROM student__c 
                     ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1 ].zipcode__c;
```

What the Meaning of this line..

Comment: what is the issue with this?

Comment: i dont understand why we written " .zipcode__c " at end of this line.

Comment: you are randomly selecting a Student__c record and getting the value of the field zipcode__c from that. then assigning this value to a variable zipCode

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a `zipcode__c` field value from `student__c` object record to the decimal variable **zipCode**

The below query gets **only** the zipcode value

```
Decimal  zipCode = [SELECT zipcode__c FROM student__c 
                     ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1 ].zipcode__c;
```

The below query can get you a complete student record.

```
Student__c student = [SELECT zipcode__c,Name,Id FROM student__c 
                     ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1 ];
```

Using the 2nd query, you can get `student.Name` or `student.zipcode__c` or `student.Id` etc (Add more fields as you need in the query)

Comment: WHAT IS DIFFERENCE B/W THE TOW LINE   ...Decimal  zipCode = [SELECT zipcode__c FROM student__c 
                     ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1 ].zipcode__c;   AND  Decimal  zipCode = [SELECT zipcode__c FROM student__c 
                     ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1 ]

Comment: updated my answer!

Comment: How can you say you get the "complete student record" by querying just zipcode, Name and Id. There might be more fields...

Comment: haha, i meant we "can" get complete record (if we want).  however, I did mention only the fields that i used in the query.  Will update though

Answer (score 1):

The line is a shorthand version of following code:

```
student__c studentInstance = [SELECT zipcode__c FROM student__c ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1];
Decimal zipCode = studentInstance.zipcode__c;
```

I would recommend assigning the query results to a list and then accessing the instance using `0th` index, or putting the query in a `try-catch` block catching the `QueryException`.